# system("net user /add " << x << " " << z); variables in system("");

Tags: c++, system

I had no hope for this to work when I first wrote this because I just took a wild guess but I mean there has got to be some way to use variables in system(""); This is what I tried

```
system("net user /add " << x << " " << z);
```

oh and x and z are global strings or is the proper term public strings when a variable is outside a function but not inside a class ether also the value of x is the name of the new user and z is the password.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+concatenate+strings

Comment: You need to construct the string first and then pass the complete string to system.

Answer (score -1):

`system()` takes a `const char *`. You must use `strcat()` and pass 1 C-style string to the function:

```
char command [100] = "net user /add";
strcat(command, x);
strcat(command, " ");
strcat(commad, z);
system(command);
```

This is a basic version.

Comment: I downvoted because of the fixed size array and usage of `strcat`. This is a security problem. The safe way to do it is a `std::ostringstream`.

Comment: @WernerHenze actually even the use of `system()` is a security problem, but I don't see you downvoting the original question.